# remove animated object from canvas windows store app

Tags: c#, events, animation, windows-store-apps

im making simple game in c#. I want to add object to a canvas, animate them and remove after tapping. Adding objects to a canvas and animating them works, but i can't remove them from this canvas by tapping.
I write that:

```
el.Tapped += (sender, args) =>
                         {
                             LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(el);
                         };
```

el is an ellipse which will be animated.

The method to animate object:

```
private void MoveAnimation(Ellipse el, double x, double y, int time)
    {
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time));

        // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

        myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
        myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = duration;

        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, el);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, el);

        // Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
        // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, "(Canvas.Left)");
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, "(Canvas.Top)");
        myDoubleAnimation1.To = x;
        myDoubleAnimation2.To = y;

        // Make the Storyboard a resource.
        LayoutRoot.Resources.Add(_animationId++ + "", sb);
        // Begin the animation.
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Tap event isn't invoked while object is in animation. If the object is after animation, tap event works. How to fix? Thx.

edit:
My code to add object to a canvas and animate its:

```
Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
        el.Width = 50;
        el.Height = 50;
        var ib = new ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource =
              new BitmapImage(
                new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/fly.png")
                )
        };
        el.IsTapEnabled = true;
        el.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        el.Tapped += (sender, args) =>
                         {
                             LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(el);
                         };

        Canvas.SetLeft(el, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(el, 0);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(el);

        MoveAnimation(el, LayoutRoot.ActualWidth-400, LayoutRoot.ActualHeight-400, 5000);
```

Comment: Where (and when) do you attach the `Tapped` event ?

Comment: I add content of the method where i attach Tapped event to the first post.